# Azure Data Factory and Person or Group SharePoint Data Types

Tags: sharepoint, azure-data-factory

Importing in a SharePoint List using Azure Data Factory and some funny behavior with the generic Person or Group SharePoint Data Types columns like Created by and Modified by .

In the SharePoint it says just say for a row for the Created By COLUMN it says , John Smith.

When imported into Azure Data Bricks with Azure Data Factory it say CreatedByID is 20.

On the Microsoft SharePoint to Microsoft Azure Data Factory doc it says :

[image]

Suppose there can be more than one John Smith . Any idea how to work round this and bring in the actual names from SharePoint ?

Comment: It's hard to understand your problem. Can you show us any details about error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be another list on the SharePointsite called ‘User Information List’ or and the ID will join to that. Within SharePoint this list will hold the User details such as Name, Email, Job Title etc. So a lookup table to solve this .